# Why does this debug build reference a release library?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, xcode4

I just installed Xcode 4 and am getting this error in my project:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LDebug-iphonesimulator4.3'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Projects/BuildOutput/Release-iphoneos/libMyFramework.a, missing required architecture i386 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture i386: 
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyRandomNumber", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in myAppDelegate.o 
objc-class-ref in RootViewController.o
```

I have the project set to iOS 4.3 Simulator.  I did check that scheme and it is set to debug build configuration. Why does it reference a Release version of the above library?

Also, what is the `i386` error about?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this type of error as well.  The odd part is that I've been building, linking, and running successfully under the Simulator.  I just now tried to fire my app up in my iPhone, and am totally bombing out during the link process.

I've run my app on my iPhone before.  I've been building it under Xcode 3.2.x for the last year, and have never seen this problem.

A couple of other SO threads indicate that it could be due to copying a framework into the project folder, and that one should just "move the framework."  Okay.  Where, and how do I let Xcode know where it is?  And if that's not the problem, then what is?

Xcode 4 has a ton of promise, but it is a sore pain in the ass sometimes....